# More Django static 404 issues - paired with ember

Tags: python, django, ember.js

I've seen lots of different posts regarding the Django static file issues.  Unfortunately, none of them seem to help me.  My django admin css is fine, however static files are giving my a 404 error.  Here is a description of what my problem:

In settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/me/develop/ember/myproj/static/'
```

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My project directory:

```
> static
  > myproj
    > app
      > templates
        > ember.hbs
    > img
      > test.jpg
```

Inside my `ember.hbs` I reference the `test.jpg`, but I get a 404 error.  It's weird because I can actually pull up the image using:
`file:///Users/me/develop/ember/proj/static/myproj/img/test.jpg`

I have no idea what to do to fix this, I've tried using the `STATICFILES_DIRS` method mentioned here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks in advance!

More information:  Django 1.8 and Ember-CLI.
I'm hosting the ember project within the `static` dir.
I'm running `python manage.py runserver` and running django on port 8000 at the same time as running `ember s` and running the application on port 4200.  I'm using CORS-headers (https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) to allow cross-site calls on development.

Comment: Are you using /static/myproj/img/test.jpg in your html to load this file ?

Comment: 1) What is URL to that test.jpg when django project (get full path from view source), 2) Are you running django with Apache or some other server?

Comment: Yes @cafebabe1991, I'm using exactly that in my ember.hbs.

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar

1)  The url from source:
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:4200/static/myproj/img/test.jpg"
2)  I'm running the django project on http://localhost:8000 and using CORS headers (https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) to allow cross server calls on my development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember and Django really shouldn't live in the same project.  They are completely different frameworks with different tooling.

Think of your Django project as the backend application that serves an API.  Think of your Ember project as one of possibly many clients that will consume your API.  Others might include mobile applications, partner services, and so on.

When I start a new project that is going to use Django and Ember, I start a Django project called "myproject":

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

And separately, an Ember project called "myproject-web":

```
ember new myproject-web
```

In development, I'll have two tabs open in Terminal.

First tab:

```
cd myproject
./manage.py runserver
```

Second tab:

```
cd myproject-web
ember serve
```

In production, I'll have two different servers, one at app.myproject.com that serves the Django application, and another one at myproject.com that serves the Ember application.

Later on, I might start a Swift project in a repository called "myproject-ios", and a Java project called "myproject-android".  You get the idea.

Comment: One of my professors told me the same thing.  I should've set it up this way from the start, and might just have to redo parts of the project still.  During development, while they're pointed at two different places, how do you interact?  For example, I have drf serving django api and I want to create an ember login to pass un/pw to django - currently I'm implementing CORS-headers for this and then I'd put the project together on production (obv w/o CORS).  Is that the same method that you'd use?  This may be another topic all together, but since you've been so kind to elaborate, I want to ask

Comment: for authentication, you'll want to do some sort of credentials exchange for a token with your API, just like you would do with any other third-party API.  there are several ways to go about this, but a very basic token authentication is easy to set up with Django.  i am actually working on a blog post and example project on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Static files will be discovered in "apps" that you create (found in `INSTALLED_APPS`) or in additional directories that you specify in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Let's say I did:

`django-admin.py startproject myproject`

And then:

```
cd myproject
./manage.py startapp myapp
mkdir myapp/static
mkdir myproject/static
```

Would give you a directory structure that looks something like

```
/Users/me/develop/myproject/
  > myapp/
      > migrations/
      > static/
      > __init__.py
      > admin.py
      > models.py
      > tests.py
      > views.py
  > myproject/
      > static/
      > __init__.py
      > settings.py
      > urls.py
      > wsgi.py
  > manage.py
```

And then in settings.py you add "myapp" to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

In this structure, `myapp/static/` files will be automatically discovered by Django because it is an installed app with a static directory.  However, `myproject/static/` files will NOT be discovered automatically because "myproject" is not in `INSTALLED_APPS` (and it shouldn't be).

This is because of the default `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting, which is:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
]
```

The first finder, `AppDirectoriesFinder`, scans the directories of all of your `INSTALLED_APPS`, and discovers any "static" folders they might contain.

The second finder, `FileSystemFinder`, scans extra directories that you specify in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, which is an empty list by default.

So if you want those files in /Users/me/develop/myproject/myproject/static/ to be discovered (as you probably do), you can add this to your settings.py:

```
from os import pardir
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

# Get the root directory of our project    
BASE_DIR = abspath(join(dirname(__file__), pardir))

# Add our project static folder for discovery
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # /Users/me/develop/myproject/myproject/static/
    join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject', 'static'),
)
```

Now, all of this is separate from `STATIC_ROOT`, which is a place where all static files are **copied** when you run `./manage.py collectstatic`.  For projects just starting out, this is usually in the project root folder: /Users/develop/me/myproject/static/

So we would add, in settings.py:

```
# /Users/me/develop/myproject/static/
STATIC_ROOT = join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

But this is only really used in production—it's a way to compile all of your static assets into a single spot, and then point /static/ at it with your server (e.g. NGINX).

During development, you can skip collectstatic altogether, and have Django discover and serve your static assets on the fly.  Django provides a "serve" view to do this in `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve`.

Try this in your urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve


admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
      url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve),
    ]
```

In your example, you are asking Django to serve files from `STATIC_ROOT`, which is also fine, but requires you to run `./manage.py collectstatic` first, and every time your static assets change—which can be a hassle.

Comment: dustin - just that url?  Or am I supposed to direct to the `img` dir using the `path`?  I ask, because as is, it unfortunately did not help.

PS- big fan of your stuff!

Comment: Actually, your problem might be where you're putting your static files.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks dustin, I've added more information above if it helps.

Comment: Ok, I just elaborated more on how static files discovery works in Django.  Let me know if that helps, or if I'm off track.

Comment: I am adding another answer based on your updated information regarding ember-cli

Answer (score 0):

In order to serve the static files into your django project you just need to add these lines to your `settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

and then in the main stucture of your project dictory needs to be like

```
>Project_dir
>App_dir
>static_dir
>templates
>manage.py
```

place your css, js, and other static contents into your static_dir